# Export elasticsearch result into csv

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to export Elasitcsearch result into CSV format in `Elasticsearch 1.3.0`. I found two suggestion for that. But these solutions aren't working for me.

- Using `head plugin` structure query option but its limitation to export 25k records only.
- Using [Elasticsearch-CSV](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-csv) plugin , Unfortunately I am unable to find it for `Elasticsearch-1.3.0`. This plugin jar available for `1.4.0` version.

Any other Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep using tools from the Elasticsearch stack (named **ELK**), 
you could use an ETL named [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) (the `L` from **ELK**).

Create a configuration based on following :

- input : [elasticsearch](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/elasticsearch)
- output : [csv](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/csv)

Besides this, it's also a [very requested feature](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1992) for Kibana 4 (the `K` from **ELK** stack, visualization webapp based on ElasticSearch cluster), which should be implemented in near future.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Though still I haven't tried Logstash. But your suggestion looks relevant . I'll try Logstash. Thanks for sharing..